# Intent to receive notification about BLE connection event on Android peripheral

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm developing an peripheral mode BLE application that runs on Android. There are a couple of excellent functional examples that describe how to develop peripheral mode applications [here](https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples/tree/master/BluetoothGattPeripheral) and [here](http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/index.html).

There is one minor difference between the sample applications and the system I need to develop. In the sample applications the GATT server runs on the peripheral mode device. Peripheral advertises, central scans and locates the device and sends a request to the GATT server.

In my system the GATT server will be on the central mode device. Peripheral will receive a connection request, needs to find the address of the requesting device and initiate a connection to the GATT server on the central mode device.

**Nomenclature and Detailed Operation**

MyApp (BLE peripheral; advertiser, GATT client)

TgtDev (BLE central; scanner, runs GATT server)

1. TgtDev is constantly scanning and looking for adverts with a specific UUID.
2. MyApp is launched and starts to advertise its presence.
3. TgtDev detects MyApp and sends a connection request.
4. On receiving connection request MyApp will request user to accept or deny connection request. At this point it will need to read the address of the device requesting the connection.
5. If user accepts, MyApp will request to connect with the GATT server on TgtDev.
6. If user denies request, MyApp will stop advertising.

Code for my application is shown below. I want to receive an intent on MyApp when a connection request is received. Looks like this should be possible with the appropriate intent filter to registerReceiver(). However, I do not see the BroadcastReceiver being called when a connection request is being made.

An implementation of the GattCallback() function is provided but is not used. To register the callback I need the address of the device I need to connect with.

Any suggestions on what I'm missing here?

EDIT: Adding information about the system and Android log messages.
Peripheral device Nexus 6 running 5.1. MyApp targetSdkVersion 21. Tracing the code path on the TgtDev I can see that MyApp accepted the connection event. I was able to confirm this with a BLE sniffer.

Log messages.

```
I/ActivityManager(  802): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.user.advertiser/.PeripheralActivity (has extras)} from uid 10034 on display 0
V/WindowManager(  802): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{2ff62ab token=Token{225f8cfa ActivityRecord{f3dc325 u0 com.example.user.advertiser/.PeripheralActivity t89}}} to stack=1 task=89 at 0
V/WindowManager(  802): Adding window Window{2d18b520 u0 Starting com.example.user.advertiser} at 3 of 9 (after Window{14f690b7 u0 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GEL})
D/BluetoothManagerService(  802): checkIfCallerIsForegroundUser: valid=true callingUser=0 parentUser=-10000 foregroundUser=0
D/BluetoothManagerService(  802): checkIfCallerIsForegroundUser: valid=true callingUser=0 parentUser=-10000 foregroundUser=0
D/BluetoothLeAdvertiser( 4018): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
V/WindowManager(  802): Adding window Window{16d3a650 u0 com.example.user.advertiser/com.example.user.advertiser.PeripheralActivity} at 3 of 10 (before Window{2d18b520 u0 Starting com.example.user.advertiser})
I/ActivityManager(  802): Displayed com.example.user.advertiser/.PeripheralActivity: +129ms
E/bt-att  ( 3236): MTU request PDU with MTU size 517
W/bt-att  ( 3236): Call back not found for application conn_id=3
W/bt-att  ( 3236): Call back not found for application conn_id=4
W/bt-att  ( 3236): Call back not found for application conn_id=5
W/bt-btif ( 3236): info:x0
E/BluetoothRemoteDevices( 3236): aclStateChangeCallback: Device is NULL
W/bt-btif ( 3236): bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=3 connected=0 conn_id=3 reason=0x0016
W/bt-btif ( 3236): bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=4 connected=0 conn_id=4 reason=0x0016
W/bt-btif ( 3236): bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=5 connected=0 conn_id=5 reason=0x0016
E/bt-btm  ( 3236): btm_sec_disconnected - Clearing Pending flag
E/BluetoothRemoteDevices( 3236): aclStateChangeCallback: Device is NULL
W/PackageManager( 1045): Failure retrieving resources for com.example.user.advertiser: Resource ID #0x0
```

Application code

```
    public class PeripheralActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "PeripheralActivity";

    private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothLeAdvertiser mBluetoothLeAdvertiser;

    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mConnectedDevices;
    private ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> mConnectedDevicesAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView list = new ListView(this);
        setContentView(list);

    mConnectedDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    mConnectedDevicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mConnectedDevices);
    list.setAdapter(mConnectedDevicesAdapter);

    /*
     * Bluetooth in Android 4.3+ is accessed via the BluetoothManager, rather than
     * the old static BluetoothAdapter.getInstance()
     */
    mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // extraneous code; check if bluetooth is on, advertising is supported etc.

    registerReceiver(intentReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
    mBluetoothLeAdvertiser = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
    startAdvertising();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopAdvertising();
    if (intentReceiver != null)
    {
        unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
    }
    }

     /*
     * Callback handles all incoming requests from GATT clients.
     * From connections to read/write requests.
     */
    private BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionStateChange "
                +DeviceProfile.getStatusDescription(status)+" "
                +DeviceProfile.getStateDescription(newState));

        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "connected");

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "disconnected");

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING) {
            Log.i(TAG, "attempting to connect");

        }
    }      

    private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent receivedIntent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Entered intent receiver");
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals(receivedIntent.getAction()))
        {
            Log.v(TAG, "Received Pairing request");
        }
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(receivedIntent.getAction()))
        {
            Log.v(TAG, "connected");
        }
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(receivedIntent.getAction()))
        {
            Log.v(TAG, "disconnected");
        }
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(receivedIntent.getAction()))
        {
            Log.v(TAG, "action found");
            BluetoothDevice foundDevice = receivedIntent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Log.v(TAG, foundDevice.getName()+" "+foundDevice.getAddress()+" was found");
            BluetoothDevice foundDeviceClass = receivedIntent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_CLASS);
            Log.v(TAG, "BT class: "+foundDeviceClass.toString());
        }
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(receivedIntent.getAction()))
        {
            Log.v(TAG, "bond state changed");
        }
    }
    };

    /*
     * Initialize the advertiser
     */
     private void startAdvertising() {
    if (mBluetoothLeAdvertiser == null) return;

    AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
            .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED)
            .setConnectable(true)
            .setTimeout(0)
            .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_MEDIUM)
            .build();

    AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
            .setIncludeDeviceName(true)
            .addServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(DeviceProfile.SERVICE_UUID))
            .build();

    mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(settings, data, mAdvertiseCallback);
    }

    /*
     * Terminate the advertiser
     */
     private void stopAdvertising() {
     if (mBluetoothLeAdvertiser == null) return;

     mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.stopAdvertising(mAdvertiseCallback);
    }

    /*
     * Callback handles events from the framework describing
     * if we were successful in starting the advertisement requests.
     */
    private AdvertiseCallback mAdvertiseCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Peripheral Advertise Started.");        
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Peripheral Advertise Failed: ");
    }
    };      


    private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {

    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);

    return intentFilter;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing a similar issue now.

Comment: I would also like to know if you ever found a solution to this.